# Registry Powershell Output

Tags: windows, powershell, conditional-statements, registry, regedit

I need your help

I need to print an logic condition in the specifc PowerShell output command.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsNT\TerminalServices' -Name fDisableCdm | Select fDisableCdm
```

I wrote a little script for test, but in my script I made a own conditional output. But I want print that what value have inside registry key and not print an own condition.

My script

```
if ($process=Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsNT\TerminalServices' -Name fDisableCdm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {write-host "1"} else {write-host "0"}
```

You can help me ?

I waiting for help and tanks for all !

Comment: So you just want the value of the property? What about your else statement?

Comment: `$process.fDisableCdm` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$regKey = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsNT\Terminal Services"
$regValue = 'fDisableCdm'

Try {
    $process=Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name $regValue -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Output (-join($regValue,": ",$process.$regValue))
}
Catch {
    Write-Output "There was an error: $($PSItem.ToString())"
}
```

You will need to check to see if your registry key for Terminal Services has a space or not.  Mine has a space.
Otherwise, this script allows you to set the two variables at the beginning of the script, performs the requested lookup and, if no error occurs, outputs the requested information.

In the event of an error, the script outputs an appropriate error message.

Reference for meaningful error handling:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.1